# Julia extremely slow behind firewall

Tags: github, julia, proxies

I work at an organization where I need proxies. I don't know much about the network security and how it is set up, but I do know that it makes adding and building Julia packages extremely slow. Is there some way to speed this up or am I fundamentally limited by whatever network bottlenecks my organization has in place? Can I speed up the way Julia interfaces with Github to make the package download process faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check first is using a custom *local* metadata repository would be enough to speed up the process.
See "[Custom METADATA Repository](https://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/packages/#custom-metadata-repository)"

> By default, Julia assumes you will be using the official [`METADATA.jl`](https://github.com/JuliaLang/METADATA.jl) repository for downloading and installing packages. You can also provide a different metadata repository location.

That means creating a local Git repo that you can access without needing your proxy.

Comment: The problem with this is that I still have to call git pull whenever I would like to update any of the packages. So in the end I have to go through the firewall.

Comment: @xcski I agree. I generally try to use an artifactory repository like artifactory (https://www.jfrog.com/open-source/) to mirror the remote resource, but here https://pkg.julialang.org/ is *not* supported.